# clickable image to select photo to upload in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my sample code please someone help us

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" name="OriginalLocation" id="OriginalLocation">
<img id="output" height="100" width="100" src="../../images/addphoto.png" alt="Add Picture"/>

<script>
  var loadFile = function (event)
  {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to preview the image before it gets upload?

Comment: what I want is to click the <img> and select a photo from my computer